# How can I replace a nan value in an "object" column?

Tags: python, dataframe, nan, fillna

How can I replace a nan value in a column which is an 'object', contains other str and ensure it goes into the main df and not just the slice.

I have tried this

```
covid_19_df.Country_code.fillna('OT')
```

but it is still empty

```
 D    Country_code    Country   
 1.   OM              Oman  
 2.   OM              Oman  
 3.                   Other
 4.                   Other 
 5.                   Other
```

I want it to look like this

```
 D    Country_code    Country   
 1.   OM              Oman  
 2.   OM              Oman  
 3.   OT              Other
 4.   OT              Other 
 5.   OT              Other
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fillna` does not replace inplace by default, you have to save the operation:

```
covid_19_df.Country_code = covid_19_df.Country_code.fillna('OT')
```

If you have empty strings instead `NaN`, you can `replace` them by `pd.NA`:

```
covid_19_df.Country_code = covid_19_df.Country_code.replace('', pd.NA).fillna('OT')
```

Output:

```
>>> covid_19_df
  Country_code Country
0           OM    Oman
1           OM    Oman
2           OT   Other
3           OT   Other
4           OT   Other
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers, it appeared i had both  occurrences of nan and ‘ ‘, but was only looking at the empty string while replacing nan, I was able to figure that out after your explanation, after trying another data and discovered it worked easily.